# Converting from storing uploads in wp-content/blogs.dir to wp-content/uploads/sites

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I recently upgraded an old Wordpress multisite website, it was created before WordPress 3.5. It used the blogs.dir to store images. Is it possible to convert the site to using the wp-content/uploads/sites instead of blogs.dir to store uploads from the various sites in the multisite install ?  If so how would I do it ?

I tried removing the blogs.dir folder and removing this from htaccess the following line:

```
# uploaded files
#RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

I then tried uploading to the media library and it recreated the blogs.dir folder. Did not store in uploads/sites..